# How to bring a redirected user account back from the dead in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, file-permissions, folder-redirection

A user at the place where I work left the company, we deleted his account out of AD and then he came back...and now his redirected profile exists, but with the wrong permissions on the folder.. I asked a coworker about it and from what I understood I threw together the following procedure (which still doesn't work, the user still gets a 502 error in the logs and no redirected desktop);. this is bad because he needs to access his old files:

Set security permissions on the folder correctly

### 1. Took ownership of the folder as Administrator

1. Right clicked `\\somersrv\x$\Redirected\<username>` and selected `properties` from the menu.
2. Clicked the `Security` tab.

   1. Clicked the `Advanced` button

      1. Clicked the `owner` tab
      2. Noticed that the owner was a UUID string...`S-1-5-21-23423431` (which indicates the original owner has been removed)
      3. Clicked the `Edit...` button.

         1. The `Advanced Security Setting for <username>` dialog appears
         2. On the `owner` tab, clicked `Other users or groups` button

            1. The `Select User, Computer, Service Account, or Group` dialog appears.

               1. In the `Enter the object name to select` textbox I typed `somedomain\administrator`
               2. Clicked `OK`
            2. Selected `somedomain\administrator` from the `Change Owner to:` list box.
            3. Checked off the `Replace owner on subcontainers and objects`
            4. Clicked `OK`
            5. The `Windows Security` dialog appeared with the following message:

               - If you have just taken ownership of this object, you will need to close and reopen this object's properties before you can view or change permissions.
            6. I clicked `OK` on all the remained dialog boxes to close everything out.

### 2. Took ownership of the folder as the user

(same procedure as above, except I selected the `<username>` as the owner instead of the administrator)

### 3. Set Security Permissions correctly for the user

1. Right clicked `\\somersrv\x$\Redirected\<username>` and selected `properties` from the menu.
2. In the `<username>` Properties Dialog:

   1. Clicked `Edit...`
   2. The `Permissions for <username>` dialog appears

      1. Clicked `Add..`
      2. The `Select Users, Computers, Service Accounts, or Groups` dialog appears

         1. In the `Enter the object names to select` textbox entered `somedomain\<username>`
         2. Clicked `OK`
   3. Back in the `Permissions for <username>` dialog box,

      1. Clicked `<user>` from the `Group or user names` list.
      2. In the `Full Control` row, in the `Allow` column checked off the checkbox.
      3. In the `Full Control` row, in the `Allow` column unchecked the checkbox.
      4. Clicked `OK`
   4. Clicked `OK` on the remaining dialog boxes until they all closed.

The standard set of permissions my coworker specified are already added to the users folder...they were:

- `SYSTEM`
- `Domain Admins`
- `<username>`

My coworker also eluded at the end of his messages to something about making the `SYSTEM` the owner, not sure what he meant; he also said to check the other user directories, but the permissions on them don't seem to adhere to much of a standard.  Some of them won't even let me look at the permissions or the owner even when I'm logged in as administrator.

But in the end the user's `Desktop`, `My Documents`, and `Favorites` appeared in the folder but now they have the user as the owner and only the `somedomain\administrator` listed under the permissions, and they still get the 502 error.

Why does the user still get the 502 error when logging in?

Also, is there another way to do this?  Using the command line or powershell or something like that?  The Microsoft UI for this is atrocious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q: is there another way to do this?

A: Do yourself a favor and backup his old data and then delete his profile and redirected folders. Then allow Windows to create his user profile and redirected folders on first login. Then restore the data to the new redirected folders.

Currently you're dealing with two different security entities (SID's) even though the old and new user accounts have the same name. Trying to get the permissions set correctly on the folders for the new SID is just going to frustrate you and you'll probably wind up with a big mess.

Comment: Actually this didn't work...thank you for your answer though.  Something on the network here must be different.

Comment: What didn't work? Did Windows not create a profile and/or redirected folders for the user?

Comment: No it didn't...yes I know it sounds like the right answer to me too..maybe on a normal network...or maybe it's because I manually deleted the local user profile instead of using `Advanced -> User Profiles` to delete the profile and it kept logging in with a temporary profile.  I'm very new at this, so I just deleted the user profile folder.

Comment: No, that's not the right way. You've deleted the profile folders but you haven't deleted the profile registry hive. Go into the Advanced System properties and look for an "unknown" profile and delete that.

Comment: I didn't include that issue in my previous post, so I'll select your answer as the right one, but I'm adding what we in my answer below.  Ok?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what we did:

## On the server

1. Login as Administrator on the server that has the redirected folders...
2. Copy the old folder to somewhere else...
3. Create a new folder with that username
4. **Make sure the user has control of the folder**

   1. Right clicked `\\somersrv\x$\Redirected\<username>` and selected `properties` from the menu.
   2. In the `<username>` Properties Dialog:

      1. Clicked `Edit...`
      2. The `Permissions for <username>` dialog appears
      3. Clicked `Add..`
      4. The `Select Users, Computers, Service Accounts, or Groups` dialog appears

         1. In the `Enter the object names to select` textbox entered `somedomain\<username>`
         2. Clicked `OK`
      5. Back in the `Permissions for <username>` dialog box,

         1. Clicked `<user>` from the `Group or user names` list.
         2. In the `Full Control` row, in the `Allow` column checked off the checkbox.
         3. In the `Full Control` row, in the `Allow` column unchecked the checkbox.
         4. Clicked `OK`
      6. Clicked `OK` on the remaining dialog boxes until they all closed.
5. **Make sure the user not the administrator is the folder owner**

   1. Right clicked `\\somersrv\x$\Redirected\<username>` and selected `properties` from the menu.
   2. Clicked the `Security` tab.

      1. Clicked the `Advanced` button

         1. Clicked the `owner` tab
         2. Clicked the `Edit...` button.
         3. The `Advanced Security Setting for <username>` dialog appears

            1. On the `owner` tab, clicked `Other users or groups` button

               1. The `Select User, Computer, Service Account, or Group` dialog appears.

                  1. In the `Enter the object name to select` textbox I typed `somedomain\<username>`
                  2. Clicked `OK`
               2. Selected `somedomain\<username>` from the `Change Owner to:` list box.
               3. Checked off the `Replace owner on subcontainers and objects`
               4. Clicked `OK`
               5. The `Windows Security` dialog appeared with the following message:

                  - If you have just taken ownership of this object, you will need to close and reopen this object's properties before you can view or change permissions.
               6. I clicked `OK` on all the remained dialog boxes to close everything out.

## On the user machine

1. Delete any extraneous user profiles for that user on the machine

   1. Login as administrator
   2. Click Start
   3. Right-click `Computer` and click `properties`
   4. In the resulting window click `Advanced System Settings`
   5. Click the `Advanced` tab
   6. Under `User Profiles` click `Settings...`
   7. If you're sure that the user doesn't have anything important in the profiles delete 
      them here.
   8. Click `OK`
   9. If the user profile folders are still there, delete them.

      - **Note:** If you deleted the user profile folder manually you will need to delete the profile entries for that user from the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\ProfileList`
2. Log out
3. Login as the user
4. `Create Desktop`, `My Documents`, `Favorites` (if they don't exist already) in the redirection folder `\\somesrv\x$\Redirected\<username>`
5. run `gpupdate /force`

## Back on the server

1. Copy their files from the old profile back in

## Back on the machine

1. Restart
2. Log back in as the user.

Comment: From my coworker You're actually supposed to let the GPO create it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782799(v=ws.10).aspx